# Is there a Sun Grid Engine / queuing / batch job management command that pauses job submissions at a particular time point then restarts them later?

Tags: queue, batch-processing, jobs, sungridengine

I apologize in advance if this is a naïve question as I'm still fairly new to using commands like `qstat` to manage jobs on a queue.

I have several hundred jobs that I want to run but vary in how long the processes take to completion. My cluster will be going into a period of maintenance for an 8 hour period at a specific date, and I am curious if there is a way to "pause" the jobs still running at a particular timepoint, then once maintenance on my cluster is done, restart it again.

Some commands I have found include `qmod`, and `qhold` then `qrls`.

Is there anything I am missing that can allow me to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is "suspend".

If you suspend a node `qmod -sq <queue>@<node>`, the jobs on that node will pause.  You can then resume them with `qmod -usq <queue>@<node>`.

If you do not have appropriate permissions to suspend queues you can suspend individual jobs with `qmod -sj <jobID>`.

Note: If the nodes are restarted during the maintenance any job on that node, running or suspended will be killed.

These commands run when executed.  You can use ["at"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) to schedule the command to run automatically at a specific time in the future.